# My rectangle don't have the good coordinates without a zoom event in d3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I'm doing a zoom in a chart. But i have a problem.
My rectangles need a zoom event to display at the correct position, if they do not have this event, they are displayed at wrong coordinates.

I have done a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Natko/mr1250un/90/

The problem is in this part of the code (i think)

```
   this.chart.selectAll()
        .data(this.viewpoint)
        .join("g")
        .attr("x", d => this.x(d.x))
        .attr("y", d => this.y(d.y))
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", 'rectangle')
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr('fill', 'orange')
    }
```

All the attributes are working except the x and y coordinates.
But when i'm updating the coordinates with my zoom event, they are displayed in the right place.

```
change(d) {
    var newX = d.transform.rescaleX(this.x);
    var newY = d.transform.rescaleY(this.y);

    this.xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
    this.yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

      this.chart.selectAll("#rectangle")
       .attr("x", d => newX(d.x) - 2)
       .attr("y", d => newY(d.y) - 5 )
  },
```

And here is the `this.x` and `this.y`

```
  this.x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

  this.y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

  this.xAxis = this.chart.append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(0, ${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`
    );

  this.yAxis = this.chart.append("g");
```

Anyone have an idea to fix my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors and here are the main points:

1. You add a `<g>` element and set its `transform` (I saw it in the fiddle, not in the question's code sample) according to `x` and `y`, it's OK.
2. You add a `<rect>` under each `<g>` and assign the same `id` to all. It will not work, `id` should be unique. You don't need the attribute at all, omit it.
3. You cannot use `x` and `y` attributes for a `<g>` element. You should use transform: `g.attr('transform', 'translate(x, y)')`
4. In 'change', you try to set the `<rect>` coordinates within its `<g>` instead of assign new `transform` to the `<g>` element itself. Keep the `<rect>` as is.
5. You can calculate `transform` with a simple formula: `transformedX = originalX * e.transform.k + e.transform.x`, where `e` is a D3 zoom event.

Comment: Hello @MichaelRovinsky, i updated my code with your comment (i think ) but i have another error. Basically, without event they've the good place, but when i have a zoom event, they take weird coordinates  https://jsfiddle.net/Natko/mr1250un/102/

Comment: I've done an experiment with your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/x6unm03s/ Look at the red circle during zoom/pan and see how to manage the coordinates. The circle's initial coordinates are (100,100) and they're being translated the way I described in the answer

Comment: Okay yeah i understand, but when i want to show more than one "circle", it's only the first circle showed https://jsfiddle.net/hpgt2e17/7/ (i already tried to put a "selectAll("circle") but it's not working. We can't print multiple circles in the same .append ?

Comment: You just need to replace `select` with `selectAll` at line 48

Comment: I've fixed your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/31t8az6y/ Check it out. There was an error in appending circles